# ComboBoxEx WM_PAINT?

Tags: winapi, combobox

I want to custom draw the ComboBoxEx control, but it seems WM_PAINT is never called. Is there some trick there? Also, how can I override the size of the control, it's calculated depending on font, but I need to fix it.

Comment: That happens when you enable custom draw.  No idea what "fit it" means.

Comment: Does custom draw allow you to repaint the border and the button with downward triangle as well? By fit it I mean, if I say the height of control should be, say, 15px, it should respect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combo Boxes use the older `WM_DRAWITEM` messages (sent to the box's parent) rather than the `WM_NOTIFY` with `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` codes.  I'm not sure why you think you'd see the `WM_PAINT` for the combobox, unless you've subclassed it.